# What is the best way to validate a terminal command has run successfully in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, terminal, system

I'm writing a quick Rails app and was wondering how I can validate the success an exec'd command.  The two commands I'm running are and SVN update, and a cp from one directory to another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use the [Kernel.system()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005982) method it will return a boolean indicating the success of the command.

```
result = system("cp -r dir1 dir2")
if(result)
#do the next thing
else
# handle the error
```

There is a good comparison of different ruby system commands [here](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html).

Answer (score 2):

How are you executing the external commands? The Ruby `system()` function returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the command was successful. Additionally, `$?` contains an error status.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just to be pedantic, you can't validate an `exec`'d command because `exec` replaces the current program with the `exec`'d command, so the command would never return to Ruby for validation.
2. For the cp, at least, you would probably be better of using the FileUtils module (part of the Ruby Standard Library), rather than dropping to the shell.
3. As noted above, the `$?` predefined variable will give you the return code of the last command to be executed by `system()` or the backtick operator.

Comment: Yeah, exec really threw me when I first started ruby programming. Basically, don't use it!

Answer (score -4):

For SVN update, check the version number before and after the update.

```
svn_start_version = IO.popen("svn info").readlines[4]
`svn update`
svn_end_version = IO.popen("svn info").readlines[4]
if svn_end_version > svn_start_version
  "success"
end
```

For the cp, you could do a filesize check on the original file being equal to the copied file.

```
source_file_size = IO.popen("du file1").readlines
`cp file1 file2`
dest_file_size = IO.popen("du file2").readlines
if dest_file_size == source_file_size
  "success"
end
```

Comment: What if the subversion repository was not changed? Your code would indicate failure. What if the file contents had changed but not the number of allocated blocks (and the copy operation failed)? Your code would indicate success.